# D3 grouped stacked bar chart column summation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have a grouped stacked bar chart as looks in this image,http://pasteboard.co/1BKMicBq.jpg
I want to add up the sum of the respective bars as in image.
I have a dataset which has summed values ready for displaying, which looks like,

```
var months= [
{  "key": "Jan",
  "values[0]": 25000,
  "values[1]": 25000,
  "values[3]": 25000
       },  {  "key": "Feb",
  "values[0]": 25000,
  "values[1]": 25000,
  "values[3]": 25000
       },
         {  "key": "March",
  "values[0]": 25000,
  "values[1]": 25000,
  "values[3]": 25000
       }
 ]
```

I have tried it with following code, but i'm not able to get the data over the every bar.

```
var project_stackedbar = svg.selectAll(".project_stackedbar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "g")
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Month) + ",0)"; });

project_stackedbar.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function (d) { return d.columnDetails; })
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x1(d.column);
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y(d.yEnd);
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        return y(d.yBegin) - y(d.yEnd);
    })
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.name); });
var sum = 0;

project_stackedbar.selectAll("text")
    .data(function (d) { return d.columnDetails; })
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) { return x1(d.column) })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return y(d.yEnd) + 15;})
    .text(function (d) {if (d.yEnd - d.yBegin !== 0) return "$" + (d.yEnd - d.yBegin);});

columns = svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("text")
    .data(months)
      .enter().append("text")
      .attr("x", function (d) {
          return (x1(d.column));
      })
      .attr("y", function (d, i) {
          return y(d.values[i]) - 60;
      })
      .attr("dy", "1.35em")
      .attr('style', 'font-size:13px')
      .text(function (d, i) {
          if (d.values !== 0) return d3.format("$")(d.values[i]);
      })
      .style({ fill: 'black', "text-anchor": "middle" });
```

Here i'm only able to get 3 values which will be printed in first group of the bars. I'm not able to get right x axis positions in the graph. can any one guide me here i'm going wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111336/sum-of-all-the-stacks-of-stacked-bar-chart-in-d3/31116238#31116238)

Comment: Cool Blue I had tried by looking at the same example, but i'm unable to assing var months values correctly. only first 3 values i'm getting.

Comment: OK, well, what's your thought process in not posting a working example? It's very easy to do it right here in the post using the code snippet tool.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the part of the code you are refering to is this...

```
  columns = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(months)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
      return (x1(d.column));
    })
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
      return y(d.values[i]) - 60;
    })
    .attr("dy", "1.35em")
    .attr('style', 'font-size:13px')
    .text(function (d, i) {
      if (d.values !== 0) return d3.format("$")(d.values[i]);
    })
    .style({ fill: 'black', "text-anchor": "middle" });
```

This is the part that you tried to re-use from the example I linked and in that example it is doing the totals.  Hence my assumption...

1. You are binding the `months` variable from your post to text
   elements that you are creating on a `g` on `svg`
2. You are referencing a member in that data called `column` which does not exist. You haven't included the code where you define the scale `x1` but, assuming it is accepting dates, you could try `x1(d3.time.format("%b").parse(d.key))` instead of `x1(d.column)`.
3. In the bound data you have stringified array references like "values[0]", but in your code you are referencing `d.values[i]` which does not exist in the data you provided. You need to sum the numeric values of the element like this: `d3.sum(d3.values(d))`.
4. You are subtracting 60 from your y values which will probably push them outside the viewport, the totals are already being positioned with `.attr("dy", "1.35em")`, so if you need to adjust, do it there.

Given all of this, I would guess that you need something like this:

```js
  var months= [
    {  "key": "Jan",
      "values[0]": 25000,
      "values[1]": 25000,
      "values[3]": 25000
    },  {  "key": "Feb",
      "values[0]": 15000,
      "values[1]": 25000,
      "values[3]": 25000
    },
    {  "key": "March",
      "values[0]": 5000,
      "values[1]": 25000,
      "values[3]": 25000
    }
  ];
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 35, left: 50};

  var width = 760 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(months.map(function(d) { return d.key; }))
    .rangeRoundBands([10, width-10], 0.35);
  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(months, function(d) {  return d3.sum(d3.values(d)); })])
    .range([height, 0]);

  columns = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(months)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
      return (x1(d.key));
    })
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
      return y(d3.sum(d3.values(d)));
    })
    .attr("dy", "1.35em")
    .attr('style', 'font-size:13px')
    .text(function (d, i) {
      return d3.format("$")(d3.sum(d3.values(d)));
    })
    .style({ fill: 'black', "text-anchor": "middle" });
```

```css
svg { outline: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```